# Copy Filename/Foldername Context menu

Tags: copy-paste

I search the .REG add bottom context menu just "copy filename" file or folder

important : without extention

thanx in advance :p

Comment: Can you clarify what you are asking please?

Comment: On windows 10 i am trying to add a button "copy filename" for file and folder in context menu without extention ;) exemple : right click copy filename filename : 01. Organic Funk.mp3 just copy : 01. Organic Funk

Answer (score 0):

Use  [CopyFilenames](http://www.extrabit.com/copyfilenames/download/). After installing:

[image]

Comment: Already test , no without extention :(

Comment: What do you mean by "extention"?

Comment: I think it's being asked for a solution as you provided where it add the options to the context menu, but after the copy operation per the applicable option from the menu, the extension of the file that was copied needs to be removed. I think this is what is being requested as weird as that may sounds, that's all I can think of based on the wording of the OP's question, and comments. Maybe I'm way off though.

Comment: @KoenVanRotijen Would you mind clearing the air here and confirming if this is what you are asking? You want an option available from the context menu to when you right click on a file it gives you the option to copy but where it copies the file to you want it to have the file extension removed, correct??

Answer (score 0):

yes with copyfilenames , just right click copy filename , i just want no extension

enable this option in explorer "Hide extensions for known file types"

Already try does not work ! :(